# Using subprocess.run how to save the data of each loop in a different file?

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code I want to save data of each loop in a different file. Can we store data in numpy format?

```
#My data format
#0    -2.3    1   -2.34   2   5.6

import subprocess
import numpy as np 

subprocess.run("make",shell=True)
h = [0.2,0.8,1.5]
for h_val in h:
    result = subprocess.run(["./main", "-w", "%.1f"%h_val])
    #with open("./h_%.1f"%h_val)
    #np.save("./h_%.1f"%h_val)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to let the program you run just write to standard output, and use a pipe to read it directly in the Python script (using e.g. [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `run`)?

Comment: Actually I.m not familiar that what will be the advantage of using popen over run.

Comment: There is no advantage with `Popen()` if `run` can do what you want. You should generally favor the higher-level functions and only fall back to bare `Popen()` (with all the plumbing it requires) if there is no higher-level function which does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdout` keyword argument of `subprocess.run()` does exactly this.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["make"])  # Absolutely no need for shell=True here
h = [0.2,0.8,1.5]
for h_val in h:
  with open("./h_%.1f"%h_val, 'w') as destination:
    result = subprocess.run(["./main", "-w", "%.1f"%h_val], stdout=destination)
```

It's not clear what you mean by "numpy format". This will simply connect standard output to the open file handle.

Comment: with stdout I got the desired result. But in my question I mentioned my data formate. What if I have to change dataformate to numpy array?

Comment: Then you need to capture and process the output in your Python program. Eventually writing to a separate destination in each iteration follows the same logic; open the file inside the loop, write, and close.